# Can't figure out this algorithm (recursive) on Trie operation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dictionary, computer-science, trie

Could someone help me understand the following pheudocode?

```
countWords(vertex, word, missingLetters)  
    k=firstCharacter(word)  
    if isEmpty(word)  
        return vertex.words  
    else if notExists(edges[k]) and missingLetters=0  
        return 0  
    else if notExists(edges[k])  
        cutLeftmostCharacter(word)  
        return countWords(vertex, word, missingLetters-1)  
        //Here we cut a character but we don't go lower in the tree  
    else  
        //We are adding the two possibilities: the first  
        //character has been deleted plus the first character is present  
        r=countWords(vertex, word, missingLetters-1)  
        cutLeftmostCharacter(word)  
        r=r+countWords(edges[k], word, missingLetters)  
        return r
```

The idea is that using a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) we are trying to find the number of times a word appears in our dictionary, BUT we may have missing letters.
I am lost in the `else` part.  I don't understand the logic.
For example if the first char of our word is a match we hit the last `else` and then recurse on `countWords` in the same level but with `missingLetters-1` but then isn't that an identical loop? I.e. it will compare again the first letter in the same level and so on?
Could someone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the order of the last lines was inverted as suggested by antti.huima, something still doesn't look alright to me.

If I understood it correctly, if you have `Pizza`, `Lizza` should also count if missingLetters==1, right? But then, if Lizza is not in the trie you enter

```
else if notExists(edges['l'])  
        cutLeftmostCharacter(word) # 'izza' left  
        return countWords(vertex, 'izza', 0) #vertex is 'P' I guess
```

and next you enter

```
else if notExists(edges['i']) and missingLetters=0
```

which returns 0?

Given that you already have a trie, I would suggest you take a look at the [Levehnstein Distance](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=114).

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is buggy. I suspect that for some reason the last call to cutLeftMostCharacter has been exchanged with the previous line. If the code would read

```
   cutLeftmostCharacter(word)  
   r=countWords(vertex, word, missingLetters-1)  
   r=r+countWords(edges[k], word, missingLetters)
```

it would make more sense.